# How to close a form with a if and then argument?

Tags: vba, visual-studio

I have a form1, that has a button, upon that button click i want to open another
form (form2), thats easy enough.But when form2 opens, i want to terminate form1.
How do i do that? I've been stuck for a long time!

Comment: In the in the click event, use form1's Hide action before you call form2's Show action.

Comment: Is this VBA?  Wouldn't it be VB.Net?  Please correct the tags to either get rid of VBA or get rid of visual-studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karl, you would use

`Unload Form1`

for that. So, something along the lines of:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

Then, in you button click event:

```
UserForm2.Show vbModeless
Unload UserForm1
```

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason i had to change "ShowDialog" to just "show"', everything is perfectly working now! Thank you!

Comment: My please! Good luck with the rest of your project. The error may have come because in order to load Form2 in vbModeless, Form1 must also have been loaded that way.